# Hyperlink to not editable foreign key filed in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-models

There is a thing I have a model with ForeignKey/OneToOneFiled to other model (with editable is set to False) like follow:

```
class Campus(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):
    # other fields

    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Album, editable=False, related_name='campus')
```

What I want to achieve is to have Campus admin page with link to the gallery (not editable field, just link). So there is a trick to do that provided in django documentation [link here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).

And I have done that:

```
class CampusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('gallery',)

    def gallery(self, instance):
        print 'got here'
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('/test/url', 'Test name')

    gallery.short_description = "Gallery"
    gallery.allow_tags = True


admin.site.register(Campus, CampusAdmin)
```

As a result I have visible gallery field in django admin but it is just a text (gallery name) not a hyperlink as I expect to be.

The gallery function is actually never called, as I checked.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work for me:

define a method in your `models.py` like this:

```
class Campus(TimeStampedModel, StatusModel):
    # other fields

    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Album, editable=False, related_name='campus')

    def gallery_link(self):
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('/test/url', 'Test name')

    gallery_link.short_description = "Gallery Link"
    gallery_link.allow_tags = True
```

And use `list_display` in `admin.py`:

```
class CampusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('gallery_link',)

admin.site.register(Campus, CampusAdmin)
```

if you want to work with your solution you must:

1-change `def gallery` to another name.

2-add new name to `list_display`.

```
class CampusAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('gallery_link',)
    readonly_fields = ('gallery_link',)

    def gallery_link(self, instance):
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % ('/test/url', 'Test name')

    gallery_link.short_description = "Gallery"
    gallery_link.allow_tags = True

admin.site.register(Campus, CampusAdmin)
```

Comment: Great! that works, thanks. Do you know why my version was not working ? Is it because I already have defined gallery field and the function is overridden/bypassed ?